# Java Curve Fitting with Starting and Ending Points

Tags: java, coordinates, regression, point

I am trying to fit a curve onto a set of points in Java, but am also trying to keep the starting and ending points consistent. I have tried to use polynomial regression (with varying degrees and stopping the line short near the starting and ending points), which usually produces a fairly accurate line, but often times the line travels above or below the starting or ending points.

Is there a way to have the regression function create a curve that smooths out the path of the points (by not exactly following every point) but still goes through the starting and ending points (possibly as defined by the user)?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: how many powers did you use? try 12

Comment: I have tried increasing the power count, but it just makes the curve more closely follow the points. I was looking for a curve that loosely fit the points (a lower power number) but still went through the starting and ending points.

Comment: what kind of linear regression are you using? can you post code? (i have been looking for a linear regression/nn package for java).

Comment: [linear regression forced through origin](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=bit%2Fly&oq=bit%2F&aqs=chrome.3.69i58j69i65j69i57j0l3.5627j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) yields some results which may help.

Comment: Ray Tayek, I'm using the curve fitting section from the Apache Commons Math Library (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/)

Comment: If you can perform weighted regression, you can weight all points with 1.0 - except for the endpoints, which you can give very large weights to force the curve through those points.

Comment: I tried increasing the weights on the endpoints to very large numbers, and while it does put the regression curve through those endpoints, it also makes the curve not follow the other points to the degree I was looking for.